# Via stub resonance intuition of insertion loss drop by formula

Tags: transmission-line

Resonance in transmission line occurs when the capacitative part cancels the inductive part.
Why in the case below at resonance does the S-param drop?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: A stub with a mismatched impedance , usually high impedance will  cancel the signal on reflection at odd 1/4 wavelengths and since Zo = sqrt(L\C) of path can be modelled by lumped elements as well as distributed. E.g. 0.5 to 1 nH/mm and ~ 1pF/mm next to ground.

Comment: Suppose we have a power delivery network of a driver  which has resonanse at f0.

Answer (score 1):

Some keywords or things to look up would be "standing wave resonance."

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-14/standing-waves-and-resonance/

When you have a stub and you have a signal propagating down the transmission line, you'll have part of the signal go down the stub and part of the signal going through the via (in the slide you show). If the signal is at a frequency (or wavelength) where it hits the end of the stub, reflects back, and cancels out at that point with the value of the incoming waveform, you'll have a resonance that dips down.

This is a relatively narrow-band effect, and you'll generally see several suckouts at regular spacing in the frequency domain. These are the harmonics of the wavelength that create those standing wave nodes.

Note that the quarter wavelength stub creates a standing wave/node because of the reflected signal from the (open) end of the stub. If you imagine a sine wave, the first "standing wave" length (or first place the value returns to zero) is 180 degrees out of phase. When you have a quarter wavelength, the void is caused by the signal propagating down to the end (1/4 wavelength = 90 degrees out of phase) and then bouncing back and reflecting. The distance traveled is 2X the 1/4 wavelength, which gives you half a wavelength.

To be explicit: The quarter wavelength stub is effectively 1/2 wavelength when you consider the REFLECTED waveform.

The suckout you're seeing isn't (strictly speaking) due to the impedance change, or characteristic impedance itself, it's more of a factor of standing wave type behavior. The magnitude of the dip will have to do (some) with the impedance (mis)matching.

Comment: Hello,i am viewing things with impedance and voltage dropr perspective.
Suppose we have a power delivery network of a driver  which has resonanse at f0.
resonanse is when our impedance reaches its minimal point. so how it will ruin the input signal to the buffer. higher voltage will be delivered to the driver so the reciever will get higher voltage value at certain frequency.

But how exactly resonanse can cause impedance increase thus dropping the VDD supply to the driver?(equation will be good)
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, here. When you say power delivery network (PDN) - you mean that your driver is a voltage regulator/VRM of some sort?

If so, why are you referring to a buffer? If you mean a signal on a transmission line, the answer is a bit different. I need to know which you mean. 

The resonance is the effect of the geometry of the cross section of a PCB, and the material properties of said PCB. The characteristic impedance is determined by Z=sqrt(L/C). A stub isn't an effect that you'll see in the characteristic impedance, so I'm not sure what your question is?